# Integration points and weights of 16-point Gauss quadrature on a quadrilateral

Tags: integration, quadrature

Would someone kindly point me to a reference were I can find the weights and integration points for 16-point Gauss quadrature for a quadrilateral in two dimensions, or am I expected to calculate it?

I have searched the internet but cannot find this information.

Comment: Typically you'd use the one dimensional abscissas and weights: $\int_0^1\int_0^1\, f(x, y)\, dx\, dy \approx \sum_i\sum_j\ f(\xi_i, \xi_j) w_i w_j$. Stroud and Secrest will have the values. In your case a 16-point rule would use the one dimensional 4-point rule.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this Matlab code to generate nodes and weights for Gauss-Legendre on $[-1,1]$

n=20; % fix the number of the $n+1$ nodes $x_i$ 
x=[1,0]; 
p=cell(n+2,1); 
p{1}=1; p{2}=x; 
for k=2:n+1 
$\quad$ p{k+1}=((2*k-1)/k).*[p{k},0]-[0,0,((k-1)/k).*p{k-1}]; 

end 

y=roots(p{n+2}); 

w=zeros(n+1,1); %the $n+1$ weights $w_i$ 

for i=1:n+1 

$\quad$ [~,c]=Horner(p{n+2},y(i)); 

$\quad$ [pn1,~]=Horner(c,y(i)); 

$\quad$ w(i)=2/((1-y(i)^2)*(pn1^2)); 
end

with Horner implementation:

function [y,b]=Horner(a,x) 
$\quad$ n=length(a)-1; 
$\quad$ b=zeros(n+1,1); 
$\quad$ b(1)=a(1); 
$\quad$ for j=2:n+1 
$\quad$ $\quad$ b(j)=a(j)+b(j-1)*x; 
$\quad$ end 
$\quad$ y=b(n+1); 
$\quad$ b=b(1:end-1); 
return

then you can create the mesh grid of $(n+1)^2$ nodes on the square $S=[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$

Y=flip(y); 
W=flip(w); 
t=(1:n+1); 
[~,x1]=meshgrid(t,Y); 
[y1,~]=meshgrid(Y,t); 
X1=reshape(x1,[(n+1)^2 1]); 
Y1=reshape(y1,[(n+1)^2 1]); 
[~,wx]=meshgrid(t,W); 
[wy,~]=meshgrid(W,t); 
WX=reshape(wx,[(n+1)^2 1]); 
WY=reshape(wy,[(n+1)^2 1]);

then you can change the variables as you please to adapt them on the quadrilateral you need. For $n=3$ you get the following $16$ nodes and weights on $S$:
$$\left (
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
x_i & y_i & w_i \\
\hline
  -0.861136311594053 & -0.861136311594053 & 0.121002993285602 \\
  -0.339981043584856 & -0.861136311594053 & 0.226851851851852 \\
   0.339981043584856 & -0.861136311594053 & 0.226851851851852 \\
   0.861136311594053 & -0.861136311594053 & 0.121002993285602 \\
  -0.861136311594053 & -0.339981043584856 & 0.226851851851852 \\
  -0.339981043584856 & -0.339981043584856 & 0.425293303010694 \\
   0.339981043584856 & -0.339981043584856 & 0.425293303010694 \\
   0.861136311594053 & -0.339981043584856 & 0.226851851851852 \\
  -0.861136311594053 & 0.339981043584856 & 0.226851851851852 \\
  -0.339981043584856 &  0.339981043584856 & 0.425293303010694 \\
   0.339981043584856 &  0.339981043584856 & 0.425293303010694 \\
   0.861136311594053 &  0.339981043584856 & 0.226851851851852 \\
  -0.861136311594053 &  0.861136311594053 & 0.121002993285602 \\
  -0.339981043584856 &  0.861136311594053 & 0.226851851851852 \\
   0.339981043584856 &  0.861136311594053 & 0.226851851851852 \\
   0.861136311594053 &  0.861136311594053 & 0.121002993285602 \\
\end{array}
\right )$$
Hope this helps